# MIPS Coding Assignment: Translating multiplication via repeated addition

Tags: c++, mips

I have an assignment and I have to convert a line of C++ code into MIPS and then run the code. I have been continuously getting the same error, and some suggestions on how to fix it would be great. The info needed is below.
I have been given this C++ Code to convert to MIPS.

```
int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int product=0;
if(x>y)
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
        product+=x;
if(y>x)
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        product+=y;
return product;
}
```

I have converted it to MIPS Code here:

```
multiply(int, int):
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,-48
        sd      $fp,40($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        move    $3,$4
        move    $2,$5
        sll     $3,$3,0
        sw      $3,16($fp)
        sll     $2,$2,0
        sw      $2,20($fp)
        sw      $0,0($fp)
        lw      $3,16($fp)
        lw      $2,20($fp)
        slt     $2,$2,$3
        beq     $2,$0,.L2
        nop

        sw      $0,4($fp)
        b       .L3
        nop

.L4:
        lw      $3,0($fp)
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,0($fp)
        lw      $2,4($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,4($fp)
.L3:
        lw      $3,4($fp)
        lw      $2,20($fp)
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        bne     $2,$0,.L4
        nop

.L2:
        lw      $3,20($fp)
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        slt     $2,$2,$3
        beq     $2,$0,.L5
        nop

        sw      $0,8($fp)
        b       .L6
        nop

.L7:
        lw      $3,0($fp)
        lw      $2,20($fp)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,0($fp)
        lw      $2,8($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,8($fp)
.L6:
        lw      $3,8($fp)
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        bne     $2,$0,.L7
        nop

.L5:
        lw      $2,0($fp)
        move    $sp,$fp
        ld      $fp,40($sp)
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,48
        jr      $31
        nop
```

I continue to receive this error code, and I am trying to figure out how to fix this:

```
spim: (parser) syntax error on line 1 of file D:/Sophomore Year ('21-'22)/Spring Semester - 2022/CS-3365 (Intro to Comp Org and Arch)/MIPS Assignment 2.asm
  multiply(int, int):
          ^
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `multiply(int, int):` isn't a valid label. Probably you want `multiply:`

Comment: @phuclv then I get the error: ```spim: (parser) syntax error on line 2 of file 
          daddiu  $sp,$sp,-48
                  ^```

Comment: Instead of writing the entire thing, hitting compile and panicking, why not start by writing a small handful of lines at a time and compiling that?  Write an empty function that does nothing.  Then make it return its first parameter.  Then make it return its second parameter.  Then implement the comparison and use that to return one or the other.  Now you have a template for your function, and you just need to write the loops.  Apparently the original function has a precondition that `x` is never equal to `y` and that neither parameter can be negative.  Seems rather broken to me.

Comment: `daddiu` is a MIPS64 instruction. The [SpIm home page](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/) says "Spim is a self-contained simulator that runs MIPS32 programs." It also says, "The MIPS architecture has several variants that differ in various ways (e.g., the MIPS64 architecture supports 64-bit integers and addresses), which means that **Spim will not run programs for all MIPS processors**."

Comment: What if x and y are equal?  Return 0?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the assembly generated by a MIPS64 compiler instead the one generated by a MIPS32 one. If this is a homework assignment you probably should just compile the C function manually instead of using a compiler.

Using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) you may see the assembly for a couple of MIPS32 compilers.
Here goes one of them (mips gcc 5.4) along with a sample call:

```
.data
str: .asciiz "Result: "
.text
main:

# sample multiplication
  la $a0, str
  li $v0, 4
  syscall  # print msg
  
  li $a0, 10  # test multiply 10 * 5
  li $a1, 5    
  jal multiply_int_int   # compute multiplication
  move $a0, $v0
  li $v0, 1
  syscall    # print result
  
  li $v0, 10
  syscall    # exit

multiply_int_int:
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-32
        sw      $fp,28($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        sw      $4,32($fp)
        sw      $5,36($fp)
        sw      $0,8($fp)
        lw      $3,32($fp)
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,$3
        beq     $2,$0,$L2
        nop

        sw      $0,12($fp)
$L4:
        lw      $3,12($fp)
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        beq     $2,$0,$L2
        nop

        lw      $3,8($fp)
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,8($fp)
        lw      $2,12($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,12($fp)
        b       $L4
        nop

$L2:
        lw      $3,36($fp)
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,$3
        beq     $2,$0,$L5
        nop

        sw      $0,16($fp)
$L7:
        lw      $3,16($fp)
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        beq     $2,$0,$L5
        nop

        lw      $3,8($fp)
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,8($fp)
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,16($fp)
        b       $L7
        nop

$L5:
        lw      $2,8($fp)
        move    $sp,$fp
        lw      $fp,28($sp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,32
        jr       $31
        nop
```